# Add spacing between vertically stacked columns in Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4, spacing

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a good way to manage vertical spacing between columns that transition from a horizontal stack to a vertical stack at certain breakpoints. There does seem to be a [solution when a form is involved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19822127/vertical-space-when-stacking-columns-in-bootstrap-3), but that's not the situation here. I've [tried this solution](https://coderwall.com/p/0jezca/vertical-spacing-for-bootstrap-columns), but it doesn't work when there are multiple columns that wrap in a row.

To illustrate my scenario, here's the structure of my HTML:

```
<body>

  <div class="container">

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-4">
        col 1
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4">
        col 2
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4">
        col 3
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4">
        col 4
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4">
        col 5
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4">
        col 6
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/b74a3kbs/6/

At medium-device size (md) and above, I'd like there there to be spacing between the two "rows" of columns, but no spacing above the "first row" of 3 columns and none below the "second row" of 3 columns. When the columns stack vertically at below the medium-device size (md), I'd like there to be spacing between each of the columns, but none above the first child and none below the last child.

Ideally, the solution would work regardless of how many columns (e.g., 3, 5, 6, 12) are contained within the row.

Comment: i don't think you can do that. you should try dividing in 2 rows and then you can get it done

Comment: ok, then i encourage you to suggest as a solution...certainly seems like one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I ended up making this work:

```
.row [class*="col-"] { 
   @extend .mb-4;

   &:last-child {
     @extend .mb-0;
   }

   @extend .mb-md-5;

   &:nth-last-of-type(1),
   &:nth-last-of-type(2),
   &:nth-last-of-type(3) {
     @extend .mb-md-0;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 60):

Use the new Bootstrap 4 [spacing utilities](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/spacing/). For example `mb-3` adds margin-bottom of `1rem`.
 **No extra CSS is needed.**

http://www.codeply.com/go/ECnbgvs9Ez

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
        col 1
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
        col 2
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
        col 3
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
        col 4
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
        col 5
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        col 6
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The spacing utils are responsive so you can apply them for specific breakpoints (ie; `mb-0 mb-md-3`)

If you want a **CSS solution**, use the [solution explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19822503/171456) in the related 3.x question (it's 
*not* dependent on using a form): https://jsfiddle.net/zdLy6jb1/2/

```
/* css only solution */
[class*="col-"]:not(:last-child){
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

Note: the `col-lg-4` is extraneous in your markup since `col-lg-4 col-md-4`,
is the same as `col-md-4`.

Answer (score 1):

see snippet below or **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b74a3kbs/5/)**

it will work regardless how many cols you have or rows

first ( on big screen )  all rows have `margin-bottom` except the last one
then on medium screen , the rows won't have any margin and the cols will all have margin-bottom except the **last col** from the **last row**

```css
.row {
 margin-bottom:30px;
}
.row:last-child{
 margin-bottom:0;
}
.row [class*="col-"] { 
   border:1px solid red;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
 .row { 
 margin:0
 }
 .row [class*="col-"]  {
  margin-bottom:30px;
 }
 .row:last-child [class*="col-"]:last-child{
  margin-bottom:0;
 }
}
```

```html
<body>

<h1 class="display-3">
hey
</h1>

  <div class="container">

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        col 1
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        col 2
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        col 3
      </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        col 4
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        col 5
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        col 6
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I just worked through a similar problem with a co-worker. Our solution, using only Bootstrap 4, is as follows:

```
  <div class="col-md-4">
    col 1
  </div>

  <div class="d-block d-md-none col-12 py-3"></div>

  <div class="col-md-4">
    col 2
  </div>
```

Using the class "w-100" instead of "col-12" for the middle div also works. What's happening here is the d-block makes it display on extra small devices and up, and the d-md-none makes it disappear at medium widths.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this solution:

```
@include media-breakpoint-down(xs) {
  [class*="col-sm"]:not(:last-child){
    margin-bottom: 15px;
  }
}

@include media-breakpoint-down(sm) {
  [class*="col-md"]:not(:last-child){
    margin-bottom: 15px;
  }
}

@include media-breakpoint-down(md) {
  [class*="col-lg"]:not(:last-child){
    margin-bottom: 15px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Gutters in row: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/gutters/

```
<div class="row gy-2">
  ...
</div>
```