# same space vertically and horizontally between columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Im using bootstap grid and in small devices I have two columns with a default bootstrap space between. Do you know how to give the same space to margin-bottom so the columns have the same space between both vertically and horizontally?

Below this is the example, without margin-bottom, do you know how to give a margin-bottom or top equal to the horizontal margin between the columns?

https://jsfiddle.net/wa1cjfn6/

html:

```
<div class="HomeEvents">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="content">
      <h1>
      text
      </h1>
      </div>
      </div>
         <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="content">
      <h1>
      text
      </h1>
      </div>
      </div>
       <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="content">
      <h1>
      Text
      </h1>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.content{
  border:1px solid red;
  margin-top:15px;
}
```

Comment: Easiest way is with the [spacing utils](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43208183/add-spacing-between-vertically-stacked-columns-in-twitter-bootstrap-4/43208888#43208888) that don't require extra CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap columns are styled with `padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px`. Therefore, between two columns you have 30px.

In the [forked demo](https://jsfiddle.net/eca5hkmv/) of your fiddle you will see I added `padding-bottom: 30px;` to the `.col-sm-6` class such that the space on the bottom equals the space between the two columns.

As long as the columns have equal height, you will have an evenly spaced layout.

Answer (score 1):

@JonD, Bootstrap 4 has spacing utility classes that you can apply to your markup that will help with adding margins and padding to you markup, without having to write any CSS in most cases. Here's a [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/) to the spacing utility classes for more information. In this case you can use the `mt-5` class on the last div with your `content` class. to get your desired result. See this [codeply project](https://www.codeply.com/go/AQJjSSi4fV) for it's implementation.