# Is no padding on `col` in Bootstrap 4 Grid System normal?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap v. 4 for the first time.

I have a `footer` that is using the new `flex` `col`'s and it works great on desktop. But when I switch to mobile they're stacked so closely to each other there is no vertical margin / padding.

Is this the normal behavior?

Also, I would prefer the content is centered or at least have some offset. But using offset results in top padding instead of left or right offset.

Is *that* normal behavior?

If so, what would be the recommended, "official", approach to adding top margin/padding on mobile only and offset?

Thank you!

Without Offset:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="row" id="kpc-row-10">

  <div class="container">

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-sm">
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-sm">
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-sm">
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-sm">
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
    
</div>
```

With Offset:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="row" id="kpc-row-10">

  <div class="container">

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-sm offset-sm-2">
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-sm offset-sm-2">
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-sm offset-sm-2">
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-sm offset-sm-2">
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, normal. Just add the vertical padding/margin that you need? There is no vertical margin/padding in columns or rows in bootstrap-3 either. You can center content a number of ways. You'd need to post your code with descriptions of what you've tried and what isn't working for us to help.

Comment: Okay, thank you @MichaelCoker. I think that is probably the answer to my question but I'll post the code in a moment.

Comment: Okay, I've updated it with a link to a Gist. Nothing special.

Comment: Be sure to include your code in the post itself when you can, no need for a gist here, it's just HTML. Check out how I edited your post and try to do that yourself in the future please. If your github or gist or whatever changes in a year and someone googles this post and lands here, they won't be able to reference your code if you don't include it in the post itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "they're stacked so closely to each other there is no vertical margin / padding"

As already mentioned in the comments, and [in other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19822127/vertical-space-when-stacking-columns-in-bootstrap-3), there is no vertical spacing between columns in Bootstrap. However, Bootstrap 4 has [spacing utility classes](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/spacing/) you can utilize to adjust the margins or padding...

For example `my-3` will add a **top** and **bottom** (y-axis) margin to each column.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm my-3">

        </div>
        <div class="col-sm my-3">

        </div>
        <div class="col-sm my-3">

        </div>
        <div class="col-sm my-3">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://www.codeply.com/go/ABUaBgCNbE

See my other answer for more info on the [spacing utilities](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42960338/171456).